# iOS RSS Feed Searching through NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, ios6, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, rss-reader

I was trying to make a RSS application that supports searching through the RSS feeds. My code is on Github (link: https://github.com/sammy0025/SST-Announcements). The view controller I was trying to apply the search function on is SSTAMasterViewController.

After tweaking and combining the code from Ray Wenderlich's How to make a simple RSS reader tutorial and How to add search into a table view, I keep getting errors such as this whenever I try to type into the search bar:

```
2013-06-02 16:53:44.764 SBlog Feed[2940:c07] -[RSSEntry setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7571930
2013-06-02 16:53:44.765 SBlog Feed[2940:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RSSEntry setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7571930'
```

I suspect that it may have something to do with my filterContentForSearchText method:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.articleTitle contains[c] %@",
                                searchText];

    searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_allEntries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

or my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; //Declare Cell Indent
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell==nil) {
         cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Makes individual entities for the entry

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", articleDateString];

    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell=[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=entry.articleTitle;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",articleDateString];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Nonetheless, I strongly suspect these pieces of code:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
    [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
     return YES;
}
```

and this inside if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)

```
cell=[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

My main question is how do I actually allow searching inside a Mutable Array that hooks to the Internet in this case?

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoint to see on which particular line the app crashes.

Comment: I added the 'I strongly suspect these pieces of code to say that these pieces of code was what came up when I put breakpoints on where I think the error may be.